# String as \x03\x00\x00\x00 to integer

Tags: java, string, hex

Helo:

I have a question, that I solved in c, but now I want to do it in hava:
I have a String like: '\x03\x00\x00\x00' 
This is representing an hexadecimal value of a integer. I transform to 0x03\0x00...
And now I want to obtain the integer, but I don't know how to do it in java

could someone give me some idea ?

Thanks in advance

(Is it some way to use this format ('\x03\x00\x00\x00' ) directly without use byte[] arrays? and in C can I use this format directly to build a integer (int)?)

Comment: sorry for the delay in my answer, my first idea was converting in integer.. but i will have to convert structs with diferent sizes. I will know the size (not the fields) of the struct and I have to introduce the values in this way too. so I'm looking for ideas to  can understand later how to do it by my own.thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Here is my one line solution

```
Integer.parseInt("\\x03\\x00\\x00\\x00".replaceAll("\\\\x", ""), 16)
```

Of course, you might wrap this in a function.

Comment: Yes ... but it breaks with an input like this "\x3\x0\x0\x0" ... which is "like" the example provided.

Comment: True, but given the sample, I assumed that both both hexa figures would be provided even for numbers smaller than \x10.

Comment: Well, that's the problem with one-line solutions like that.  They are fragile if your assumptions turn out to be wrong.  At least my solution will throw an exception if 1) the "\x"'s are not there, or there are too many digits in one of the components.

Comment: Making the right assumptions has nothing to do with the number of lines, and while we speak about assumptions, what happens with your solution if the inputString is just \xA0\x00 ? But let's stop the trolls and sorry for the initial taunt ,=) It's just that i don't like the word "Impossible"

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it is something like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputString);
int value = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    sc.next("\\\\x");
    byte b = sc.nextByte(16);
    value = (value << 8) | (b & 0xff);
}
if (sc.hasNext()) {
    throw new SomeException("Unexpected stuff at the end");
}
```

(**UPDATE** - corrected a sign extension bug ... and to detected unexpected stuff at the end of the input string.)

Now, if this encounters input that it can't cope with, it will throw an exception.  In this case it is designed to match a sequence of EXACTLY 4 bytes.

But (IMO) that is preferable to accepting the bad input and producing an incorrect result.  That is the risk with clever solutions that use pattern matching tricks to avoid doing proper parsing.

---

> Thanks very much for the answers I don't understand this solution completely and it give me errors in sc.next("\\x");

The errors will be because you are using this on a string that has less than 4 bytes in it, or that has something that simply doesn't match the format of your example.  If you want the code to handle sequences of less than (or more than) 4 bytes, you will need to change it.

> I would like to know why you make: `value=(value <<8) | b` (but i'm working to understand it) thanks very much

Well there was a bug in that.  I corrected it to

```
value = (value << 8) | (b & 0xff);
```

It is doing some bit-twiddling to tack the byte `b` onto the least significant end of the number in `value`.  Read up on the Java `<<` shift operator and the bit-wise `&` and `|` operators.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answers
I don't understand this solution completely and it give me errors in sc.next("\\\\x");  I would like to know why you make: value=(value <<8) | b
(but i'm working to understand it) thanks very much

Comment: now, I have it working with small changes, I use sc.useDelimiter("\\\\x"); instead of sc.next(), and I could understand your solution, Thanks very much